# Why button dont work in html and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, spring-boot

Why increment and decrement buttons dont work, they was working well but when I add `type="button"` stop working.

> html

```
<form th:action="@{/home}" method="post" style="margin-top: 10px; display: block">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px;">
          <button type="button" name="decrement"  onclick="decrement()" style="display: inline; margin-right: 5px; width: 20px" id="decrement">-</button>
          <output style="display: inline" name="quantity" id="quantity">0</output>
          <button type="button" name="increment" onclick="increment()" style="display: inline; margin-left: 5px; width: 20px" id="increment">+</button>
          <input type="hidden" name="itemId" th:value="${item.getItem_id()}"/>
          <button type="submit" name="addToCart" class="addToCart-btn">Add to cart</button>
       </div>
</form>
```

> javascript

```
function increment(button) {
    var counter = button.parentNode.querySelector("output");
    counter.textContent++;
    updateAddToCartButton(button)
}

function decrement(button) {
    var counter = button.parentNode.querySelector("output");
    if (counter.textContent > 0) {
        counter.textContent--;
        updateAddToCartButton(button)
    }
}

function updateAddToCartButton(button) {
    var quantity = parseInt(button.parentNode.querySelector("#quantity").innerText);
    var submitButton = button.parentNode.querySelector(".addToCart-btn");

    if (quantity > 0) {
        submitButton.style.display = "inline";
    } else {
        submitButton.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `th:action`?

Comment: @chovy It's a Thymeleaf directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you are using inline event handlers. In this context, `increment` refers to the button with the id of `increment` rather than the function. You also pass no argument to `increment` and `decrement` so `button` is `undefined` in both.

Use `addEventListener` with `event.target` instead.

```js
document.querySelector('#increment').addEventListener('click', e => increment(e.target));
document.querySelector('#decrement').addEventListener('click', e => decrement(e.target));

function increment(button) {
    var counter = button.parentNode.querySelector("output");
    counter.textContent++;
    updateAddToCartButton(button)
}

function decrement(button) {
    var counter = button.parentNode.querySelector("output");
    if (counter.textContent > 0) {
        counter.textContent--;
        updateAddToCartButton(button)
    }
}

function updateAddToCartButton(button) {
    var quantity = parseInt(button.parentNode.querySelector("#quantity").innerText);
    var submitButton = button.parentNode.querySelector(".addToCart-btn");
    if (quantity > 0) {
        submitButton.style.display = "inline";
    } else {
        submitButton.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<form th:action="@{/home}" method="post" style="margin-top: 10px; display: block">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px;">
          <button type="button" name="decrement" style="display: inline; margin-right: 5px; width: 20px" id="decrement">-</button>
          <output style="display: inline" name="quantity" id="quantity">0</output>
          <button type="button" name="increment" style="display: inline; margin-left: 5px; width: 20px" id="increment">+</button>
          <input type="hidden" name="itemId" th:value="${item.getItem_id()}"/>
          <button type="submit" name="addToCart" class="addToCart-btn">Add to cart</button>
       </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, it's working well when I make run on stackoverflow but when I make run on my IDE stop working

Comment: @juan Can you provide a [mre] in some form?